# Not able to execute/run vbs file from java on server

Tags: java, vbscript

I have a VBS file xxx.vbs that i'm able to execute it on my local machine using the below code:

```
 String cmd = "wscript filePath\\xxx.vbs";
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

But when i create a war file of the project and deploy it on the server, I'm not able to execute the vbs file.

I can however execute the VBS file manually on the server. So there is nothing wrong with the VBS file.

Any idea on what may be the reason for the above?

Comment: There might be filepath issue. The server might not be able to lookup the path you've provided for .vbs file

Comment: No i have checked the filepath and it is correct. The issue is that Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) is not getting executed. I have provided echo statements at the start of the VB script to check if the VBS file is executing but i'm sure that the VBS file is not executed.

Comment: "... but i'm sure that the VBS file is not executed." Yes, because it is not found! In that case, your `wscript` call exits with an error code. Do you check that in your Java coding?

Comment: @Praveen Since you are getting the Process object, call the exitValue() and log it to see the exit code..

You should always check the i/p stream and error stream to check the logs of execution

Comment: Oh, and by the way: `wscript` is a windows application, whereas `cscript` is a command line application. You most likely want to use `cscript`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below snippet to determine whats happening in the background.

```
String line="";
          try
            {
            InputStreamReader isr = process.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr,4094);
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(line);    
            } catch (IOException ioe)
              {
                ioe.printStackTrace();  
              }

          try
            {
             isr = process.getErrorStream();
             br = new BufferedReader(isr,4094);
             while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(line);    
            } catch (IOException ioe)
              {
                ioe.printStackTrace();  
              }
```

P.S. The above snippet is just for informational purpose.

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` will simply begin the execution, and exits..
Trying the above will eventually show you the exceptions, if any, and the output of the script file you are trying to run.

However, the better way is to create a seperate runnable which can accept the input stream and display its content instead of writing the code I specified above.